# ASP.NET project organization

Tags: asp.net, project-organization

This may be a broad question because part of the problem is that I actually don’t know what the question is. What I would like to know is how you commonly organise ASP.NET applications in terms of placement of pages (aspx), user controls (ascx), server controls and other support classes and utility functions etc. First, let’s assume that there is already some data layer somewhere (perhaps in a different project). This is the not issue.
The issue I frequently face is that create several pages and realize that they need to share some common rendering logic or some utility function, class etc. Another typical case is that some pages become too large so that it seems handy to split them (say into some user controls). What is the best place to put these utility classes, share classes, user controls, server control etc.? Here are several possibilities.

Don’t really care about any organisation and place all types of files next to each other. So in one directory, you may have an aspx files, some cs files etc. This is not really an option probably.

Organize files by types. Let’s say you create a directory for user controls and put all user controls there. OK, but what about server controls and other regular classes? Should they be in special directories as well? It does not sound right. What I dislike most on this is that when you work on a feature (logically related piece of code), you must hunt it all over the place. I think that features and logical sections of your applications should be also grouped on the file system level in some way.

What I would like to have is to have the pages (aspx), user controls (ascx) and handlers (ashx) basically as dummy placeholders sitting in the directory structure organized from the logically according to the point of view of the outside visitor while the actual code (page, user controls implementations, serve control and utility classes) should be placed in s different folder structured into logical namespaces (organized by the modules or features of the application). It seems to me that the only way to achieve this is to manipulate the `<%@ Page ... %>` directive manually.

Does it sound crazy? Am I asking too much? Is there a better way? What are your best practices? Do you know some good examples?

**Edit:** Another idea. This does not mess up with the generated aspx, aspx.cs and aspx.designer.cs files. One on my original requirements was that I wanted to place the code driving aspx pages to my own location and put it to a custom namespace hierarchy. So what if I simply subclass the aspx classes generated by VS? Let’s say I have a project called MyApp and `MyPage.aspx` page in it. VS then creates `MyApp.MyPage` inherited from `System.Web.UI.Page`. I leave this class be (no code will go there), but create a subclass, say in `MyApp.SomeNamespace.SomeSubNamespace.MyPage`, inherited from `MyApp.MyPage`. This way `MyApp.SomeNamespace.SomeSubNamespace.MyPage` will get access to the autogenerated protected fields corresponding to the server controls of `MyApp.MyPage` and I’ll get an entire "private" namespace for all the support classes which are related to this page. Any major disadvantages? Another related problem which bothers me is where should this new cs file be physically placed? In web projects, there is a standard folder for it called App_Code, but I’m interested in web applications. Creating a directory in the root of the application (such as Code) does not sound right.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that you can create page classes that don't actually correspond to any markup.  We often create base pages that our actual UI pages inherit from.  This is a simple way of organizing "base" page functionality.  Then when you create your .aspx pages, make them inherit from the base page class, rather than System.Web.UI.Page.

We usually place our base page .cs files into the top level directory if it's a small project, or for slightly larger projects we'll create a "Shared" or similar directory where they live.

However, we also have a huge enterprise web project, and we simply build our webcontrols and base pages into a class library called `CompanyName.Web.UI`, with a couple sub-namespaces to that.  All our actual web site projects import that assembly and all the code for the controls, etc. is elsewhere.  This sounds like it might be a good option for you.

If you remember that your .aspx codebehinds can inherit from any class file, it should make it easier for you to organize.

Comment: True. I knew about this option. The original post was getting already too long, and so I did not want to mention it. My problem I with this approach is that the superclasses don't have access to the generated protected members of their corresponding aspx pages (because they are superclasses). This brought me to another scheme which I'll insert to the original question.